# Panel Controls[i] - index out of range

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception, indexing, controls

I have a panel **Profiles List** on a web page. It contains multiple small panels, like a list of items contains lines. The items here are profiles. Each profile is actually a small panel **SingleProfile** with checkbox inside. **Checkbox** is the core here, because it has an **ID**, which is used to find the same items.

On this page there is also another similar big panel. I should add to the second panel only those items, which do not exist in the first one. So, the task is to show in the second panel only those profiles, which are not presented in the first panel. This is checked using **IDs** of the checkboxes in both lists.

To check if a newly added profile in the second panel already exists in the first panel, I try to access the ID property of each item in the first panel through **Controls[]** property. I do it in the cycle:

```
if (ProfilesPanel1.Controls.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= ProfilesPanel1List.Controls.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        //label1.Text += " "+Convert.ToString(sqlReader["chain_id"]); //Bug #2 - see Stored Procedure description
        cbx1 = new CheckBox();
        cbx1 = (CheckBox)ProfilesPanel1List.Controls[i].Controls[1]; //Bug #1 - here the Exception occurs
        if (cbx1.ID == Convert.ToString(sqlReader["chain_id"])) //if profile already exists in the first panel
        {
            //Do not add this profile to the second panel
        }
    }
}
```

The exception **"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"** occurs in the line marked with "Bug #1".

I use sqlReader which takes IDs from a stored procedure. Stored procedure works fine in the Sql Server. But, when I output values of the sqlReader into a label on a web page (see comments in the code), each value is doubled, like "1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to BUG #1**

Check number of controls and its names from quickwatch in debug mode and see, is `ProfilesPanel1List.Controls[i]` a panel or some other control. Choose your index correctly after checking it in debug mode.
And also you don't need to use `cbx1 = new CheckBox();` line of code. Its next line of code is enough to initialize that Checkbox.

Your **sqlReader** code is not enough to get the actual cause of 2nd error.

Comment: because you may have some literal control or label at 0 index

Answer (score 0):

For **Bug#1**, there is a chance that there might be no nested controls existing underneath 'Controls[i]'. So to guard against the bug, you can first check if there are any nested controls underneath the current element and then checking the type of control before type casting.

```
    if(ProfilesPanel1List.Controls[i].Controls.Count>1 && ProfilesPanel1List.Controls[i].Controls[1] is CheckBox) //Iff you are double sure about layout structure and assured that it is not going to 
//change. If changes are anticipated then again doing a foreach(..) over nested 'Controls' and type 
//checking is much better.
    {
     //Do the type conversion etc., as per your requirement.  
    }
```

For **Bug#2**, what do you exactly mean by 'each value is doubled'? As I can see that you are appending to the same Label (with ID: Label1) inside the loop so, there is a chance for the text to be concatenated on every iteration. Also, please be sure as per your requirement, whether you need to manipulate same label's text or label inside nested controls of the parent panel.